# WSO2 Carbon server - error when launching

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to run wso2 api manager from the source code. I downloaded `carbon4kernel` and the `product-apim` as stated on the site. The code builds successfully and imports into eclipse, but I can't launch the carbon server.

When I execute `wso2server.sh` I get the following:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.launcher.Main

Even if I add the class to the classpath, it finds the Main class, but I get:

> SEVERE {org.wso2.carbon.launcher.Main} - org/osgi/framework/launch/FrameworkFactory

This is using the C5 server (although the download seems to suggest carbon4) and apiman 1.9.1.

Its worth noting that the binary distribution works straight out of the box, but uses an older version of carbon (AXIS2-based), but the source code version uses OSGi.

Does anyone have this working, or point me to where its going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any products released on top of C5. So basically at the moment you cannot build API Manager with C5.

About building and running C5, which `wso2server.sh` did you try to run? I guess you tired with the one at `distribution/kernel/carbon-home/bin/wso2server.sh`. If that is the case it won't work. What you need to do is, build the project from the root pom.xml and at `distribution/kernel/target` the built zip file. Unzip it and try the `wso2server.sh` in the `bin` directory.

Alternatively, without building from source, you can download and try the C5 kernel binary from https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/releases/tag/v5.0.0